# Map array value to interface variable - Angular

Tags: angular

I'm creating an application with Angular using the pokemon api and I would like to map the value of an array to a variable of my interface.
Here is what the api returns :
[image]

Here is my interface :

```js
export interface Pokemon {
  id: number;
  pokedexId: number;
  name: string;
  sprite: string;
  apiGeneration: number;
  type: string;
}
```

I would like that the variable type of my interface get the value of apiTypes[0].name
Here is the code of my request if needed :

```js
  public getPokemons(): Observable<Pokemon[]> {
    this.generation++;
    return this.http
      .get<Pokemon[]>(this.URL + '/generation/' + this.generation)
      .pipe(
        tap(console.log),
        catchError((err) => {
          throw 'error in source. Details: ' + err;
        })
      );
  }
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: you can use it like that: `const POKEMON_DATA: Pokemon[] = [{}, {},{}]`

Answer (score 0):

You have a discrepancy between the object returned by your api and the interface you have declared. You are looking for the RxJS [map()](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) function. Inside of that function you will need to use a [javascript array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

You will end up with something like this:

```
public getPokemons(): Observable<Pokemon[]> {
  this.generation++;
  return this.http
    .get<Pokemon[]>(this.URL + '/generation/' + this.generation)
    .pipe(
      tap(console.log),
      catchError((err) => {
        throw 'error in source. Details: ' + err;
      }),
      // Suggested code starts here
      map((result) => {
        return result.map((item)=> {
          /*map item's properties to a new object matching your interface*/
          return {name: item.name, sprite: item.image} as Pokemon
        })
      })
    );
}
```